# codeigniter redirects to another page without executing controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have developed one model -view and controller in codeigniter but when i calling function of controller in url instead of executing that controller it redircts me to homepage

controller :

```
public function job_post_list()
{
    $data['job_posts']=$this->recruiter_post_job_model->get_posts();
    $this->load->view('recruiter/job_post_list',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

Model :

```
public function get_posts()
{
    $logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    $query="SELECT RPJ.*, CM.country_name, SM.state_name, CTM.city_name 
                    FROM recruiter_post_jobs AS RPJ
                    LEFT JOIN country_master AS CM ON ( CM.country_id = RPJ.country_id )
                    LEFT JOIN state_master AS SM ON ( SM.state_id = RPJ.state_id )
                    LEFT JOIN city_master AS CTM ON ( CTM.city_id = RPJ.city_id )

                    WHERE RPJ.recruiter_id = ".$logged_in['user_id']." AND RPJ.job_status = 1";

    $data=$this->db->query($query);
    if($data->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $results=$data->result();
        return $results;
    }
    else
    {
        $results=NULL;
        return $results; 
    }
}
```

any body please answer me.

Comment: please some one help as soon as possible it is urgent

Comment: ^^ Your above comment is a bit of a red flag; this isn't a helpdesk.

Comment: This code is not relevant to your question, this doesn't do redirect. Please provide relevant code.